# Prestashop - Link products details from home with relative urls

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I'm using prestashop 1.6. In my home page I have some images linking to product details on click. I set the home page template to point to destination pages using absolute urls (eg. https://www.example.com/presta/1-my-product).
But what if my domain name will change? What if the path change? I should change all the links in my site.. this is not scalable..
So I was wondering if is it possible to link subsections (like products) with relative urls?
In the documentation I can't find nothing but it's such a basilar feature..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using absolute link you have to use this in your controller

```
$my_product_link = $this->context->link->getPageLink("product",  true, (int)$this->context->language->id, array("id", <your product id>));
$this->context->smarty->assign(
            array(
                'my_product_link' => $my_product_link
            )
);
```

and then use the link in your tpl template like this

```
<a href="{$my_product_link}">something</a>
```

What i worte is:

1) Retrieve the correct product url in your controller

2) Pass the variable to your template

3) Display the variable in your template

Comment: I was hoping that It can be done by a configuration, without editing templates, but well I think it's not possible

Comment: @user1781028 with this solution you can change the domain urls and everithing will be ok